# What is "string bashing" and why is it bad?

Tags: java, string

My boss keeps using the term "string bashing" (we're a Java shop) and usually makes an example out of me whenever I ask him anything (as if, I'm supposed to know it already). I Googled the term only to find results pertaining to theoretical physics and string theory.

I am guessing it has something to do with using String/StringBuilders incorrectly or not in keeping with best practices, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 5):

"String bashing" is a slang term for cutting up strings and manipulating them: splitting, joining, inserting, tokenizing, parsing, etc..

It's not inherently bad (despite the connotation of "bashing"), but as you point out, in Java, one needs to be careful not to use String when StringBuilder would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you ask your boss for an example of string bashing.
Don't forget to ask him for the correct way of refactoring the examples he gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Out of context, "string bashing" doesn't really have any meaning in itself. It's not a buzz word for any good or bad behaviour. It would just mean "bashing strings", as in using string operations.

Whether that is good or bad depends on what you are doing, and the role of the strings would not really be important. There are good and bad ways of handling any kind of data.

Sometimes "bashing strings" is actually the best solution. Consider for example that you want to pick out the first three characters of a string. You could create a regular expression that isolates the characters, but that would certainly be overkill as there is a simple string operation that can do the same, which is a lot faster and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Effective Java has an item about using strings: "Item 50: Avoid strings where other types are more appropriate". Also on stackoverflow: "[Stringly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2444303#2444303)".

Answer (score 0):

A guess: It might imply something related to creation of unnecessary temporary objects, and in this particular case Strings. For example, if you're constructing a String token by token then it's usually a good idea to use a StringBuilder. If the String is not built using a builder, each concatenation will cause another temporary object to be created (and later garbage collected).

In modern VMs (I'm thinking HotSpot 1.5 or 1.6) this is rarely a problem unless you're in performance critical code or you're building long strings, e.g. in for loops.

Only a guess; might be better to ask what he or she means? I've never heard the term before.

Comment: StringBuilder's: tt's worth when you are in a loop. If your code only does S=A+B+C+D, then the compiler will be clever and use a StringBuilder automatically. If you have a loop that concatenates, then the compiler will not be that clever.

Comment: Yep, just edited in the part about for loops. I realized my original answer was a bit too vague/weak.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few results on google which refer to string bashing in this context. They don't appear to refer to the concern about the inefficent temporaries and using StringBuilder.

Instead, it appears to refer to simplistic string parsing. I.e. doing stuff like checking for substrings, slicing the string, etc. In particular, it appears to have the implication of it being a hacky solution to the problem.

It might be seen badly because you should either use real parsing or obtain the data in a non-string format.